# Excel VBA - Delete row if not a single cell in the row is colored in red

Tags: excel, vba

i need help with writing code for this problem and I just cannot solve it as I am a beginner in VBA.

I need to delete a row, if there is not a single cell in that row with interior.color = 3 (red)

Important is that it should not specify on a specific column, so it could be that the red colored cell is in B3 or C3 or D3.. or AC3 and so on... and not only in one column.

If someone could help me I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you need checking and deleting a single row? Or all rows in the sheet? Then, should the row be deleted if **it does not contain any red cell** or **if not all its cells ar red**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to delete all rows which **do not contain any a red cell**, try the next code, please:

```
Sub DeleteRowsRedCell()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngDel As Range
  
     Set sh = ActiveSheet
     lastR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
     lastCol = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     
     For i = 2 To lastR
        For i = 2 To lastR
        For j = 1 To lastCol
            If sh.cells(i, j).Interior.Color <> vbRed Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = sh.Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Rows(i))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
     Next i
     Next i
     Debug.Print rngDel.Address 'addresses of the rows o be deleted
     'If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

The code does not (directly) delete the rows in discussion. For testing reason, it returns in `Immediate window` the addressed of all rows meting criteria. If it is what you want, you simple comment/delete the code line `Debug.Print rngDel.Address` and un-comment the last row (`If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp`)

If you need to do something else, please better explain what is to be done...